# How to Log In to Flickr in iOS 7 with a Google Account

Tags: gmail, ios, google, flickr

iOS 7 now looks to include integration with Flickr for photo sharing.

I already have a Flickr account, though I log in using a google (gmail) account. I would expect to be able to connect this account with iOS 7 Flickr integration, but logging in with this method seems to be unavailable, and using a user@yahoo.com account seems to be the only option.

How can a Google account be connected to the iOS 7 Flickr integration (in the settings menu) without having to "start fresh" and re-upload photos and content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work-around solution I've found for this does not require "starting fresh", though it does involve some degree of "new" account creation. You must create a new user@yahoo.com email address linked to your existing account using the method below:

- Visit yahoo.com
- Click the "Sign In" option at the top right
- Choose the "Google" option to sign in with a Google account
- In the pop-up window that follows, log in with your Google/Gmail account
- Click on "Mail" in the top right
- Follow the prompts to create a new yahoo account, using a new/available user@yahoo.com email address
- Once this process is complete (was a bit "buggy" for me when creating, asking for password re-prompts then giving errors, but still did actually work), you should be able to use the username (e.g. the "MyUserName" from MyUserName@yahoo.com) and password you chose to log in to Flickr; I recommend visiting flickr.com and using these yahoo credentials to ensure your content is present as expected
- If all of the above was successful, you should be able to connect iOS 7 to Flickr via Settings > Flickr by logging in with your yahoo ID and password

Answer (score 1):

After having experienced the same issue (not being able to login to the Flickr app via iOS7 using my Google/Gmail account) I found that it is required to create a Yahoo account as mentioned.

Once I completed that, I was then provided with the additional sign-in options when launching the Flickr app (enabling me to sign-in using my Google account as desired all along).

I now have a Yahoo account I don't require for anything though (other than to support my use of the Flickr app with Google account sign-in).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better solution. Using Flickr app, attempt to login using false credentials. Basically make up a user name and password and try and login. Obviously it will say error, but will take u to another login screen of yahoo that looks slightly different. Simply click either the login with Facebook or Google from there and should work fine!

Comment: This question is specifically referring to the Flickr iOS7 integration, not the Flickr app itself (you can login without even downloading the Flickr app). Does the method you described also populate the Flickr login data in the iOS settings menu?